# Spring Import resource based on property in properties file - without using spring profile - Conditional Context Loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to import the resource based on value of property in properties file, there are several context files and spring should load only those whose value is set to true. These values are different for different customers.

```
<import if{property} = true resource="classpath*:prod-config.xml"/>
```

and I can't use spring profiles here. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring 4's [Conditionals](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) to achieve that behaviour

For instance:

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(MyConditionalProd.class)
@ImportResource("classpath*:prod-config.xml")
public class MyConditionalProdConfig {}
```

MyConditionalProd would implement the conditional logic:

```
public class MyConditionalProd implements ConfigurationCondition{

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        String property = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("someProperty");
        if("prod".equals(property)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This really helped, also in each of the context config file we can have context component scan of different package.