# Spring activate annotation only on specific profile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

My Spring security features are activated via annotation in the main class. Example below.

```
@ImportResource("classpath:/securityContext.xml")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class MySpringBackend {}
```

I want to limit this process of loading these security-related files (currently done via annotation as shown above) to only certain [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html), which I'll be passing in as program arguments.

I could not find any documentation on limiting annotations by profile. Is this possible?

Eg: Something like adding `@Profile("production")` to above annotation would limit it to the production profile.

---

Comment: can you show us the code that you've tried ? (your main class)

Comment: updated question to make it clearer. Hope that helps @Gopi

Comment: So, would you like to activate both annotations based on specific profile or activate only @ImportResource?

Comment: @Gopi I want to activate both annotations based on specific profile. If that's too difficult, even one would be ok for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have 2 different classes, each with a different Profile annotation.

Class 1 will have 1 set of annotations (aside from its profile annotation). 
Class 2 will have the other set of annotations (once again aside from its profile annotation).

On runtime, based on the active profile, only one of the two classes will be injected into the Application context. Note that only this particular classes annotations will be activated.

Answer (score 1):

Since, @Component or @Configuration can only be marked with @Profile, you need to use @Conditional annotation in combination with @ImportedResource to activate on specific profile. Check this stackoverflow page for the solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756039/spring-import-resource-based-on-property-in-properties-file-without-using-spri)

Comment: while this is not a direct answer to my question, it most certainly helped me figure it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: @john It would be good to post the answer that you found as I also have the same question as yours